# How can I get A radar chart like this by chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[radar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AZR3.png)

The y axis is vertical default, How can I rotate the y axis!

Comment: Could you please leave the code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for  [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/)

**Sample Radar in chart.js**
http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/area/radar.html

**SNIPPET**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: The y axis is vertical in this demo, but I need a chart with y axis not vertival.